# Ms Access - show difference between two query results

Tags: sql, ms-access, subquery, not-exists

I have written two queries that show different results for the same 3 fields:

All relevant data, showing ***ITEM_NUMBER*, *MFR*,** and ***MFR_PN***, returning 164 different lines

```
SELECT NewMNFData.ITEM_NUMBER, NewMNFData.MFR, NewMNFData.MFR_PN
FROM NewMNFData INNER JOIN ([B-K Data] INNER JOIN [BK-Analogic-PN-CDB2006-import] ON [B-K Data].[B-K no] = [BK-Analogic-PN-CDB2006-import].[BK PN]) ON NewMNFData.ITEM_NUMBER = [BK-Analogic-PN-CDB2006-import].[Analogic PN];
```

And another query which shows *unique* instances of ***ITEM_NUMBER*, *MFR*,** and ***MFR_PN*** which returns 101 different lines.

```
SELECT NewMNFData.ITEM_NUMBER, Min(NewMNFData.MFR) AS MinOfMFR, Min(NewMNFData.MFR_PN) AS MinOfMFR_PN
FROM NewMNFData INNER JOIN ([B-K Data] INNER JOIN [BK-Analogic-PN-CDB2006-import] ON [B-K Data].[B-K no] = [BK-Analogic-PN-CDB2006-import].[BK PN]) ON NewMNFData.ITEM_NUMBER = [BK-Analogic-PN-CDB2006-import].[Analogic PN]
GROUP BY NewMNFData.ITEM_NUMBER;
```

The difference is the uniqueness on **ITEM_NUMBER** (there are the same **ITEM_NUMBER** up to two times, with different **MFR** and **MFR_PN**)

I want to create a third query that shows all record from query 1 that is not present in query 2, showing  63 lines.

I thought of using the following query using WHERE NOT EXISTS, but it returns an empty set.

```
SELECT AllMFR.*
FROM AllMFR
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
SELECT UniqueMFR.*
FROM UniqueMFR);
```

Comment: What happens if you make names of the fields in each table the same?  E.g. - Instead of `MinOfMFR` on the unique values table, try `MFR`.

Comment: Is it possible that `AllMFR` has duplicate rows?  That could explain why your combined query returns an empty set.

Comment: Mark Moretto: The name MinOfMFR came naturally since I have to find unique values of ITEM_NUMBER, and Access automaically names the field like this.
RBarryYoung: There is no duplicate rows in AllMFR.

Comment: Deal Closers:  These are similar, but still fundamentally different questions.  Please re-open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be much easier if Access implemented all of the ISO SQL set operators (UNION, INTERSECTION, REMOVE) because what you want is the REMOVE operation (called MINUS in Oracle).  However, like MySql MS-Access only implements the UNION operator.  Fortunately, MySql has a doc page that explains [how to implement the MINUS (REMOVE) operator functionality in SQL without the keyword](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-minus/)

As it happens, you got pretty close, you just need to add an extra set of conditions to your NOT EXISTS query.

So something like this should work:

```
SELECT AllMFR.*
FROM AllMFR
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT *
    FROM UniqueMFR
    WHERE UniqueMFR.ITEM_NUMBER = AllMFR.ITEM_NUMBER
      AND UniqueMFR.MFR         = AllMFR.MFR
      AND UniqueMFR.MFR_PN      = AllMFR.MFR_PN
    );
```

Comment: This returned 99 results, instead of the 63 I expected - how come?

Comment: I altered it to the following:

SELECT AllMFR.*
FROM AllMFR
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT *
    FROM UniqueMFR
    WHERE UniqueMFR.ITEM_NUMBER = AllMFR.ITEM_NUMBER

      AND UniqueMFR.MinOfMFR_PN      = AllMFR.MFR_PN
    );

And it returned 63 lines as I hoped! Will check if the lines are correct, but thank you so, so much!

Comment: @loragi without the data rows from AllMFR and UniqueMFR and this queries output, I cannot really tell.  However, you could start by looking at a row(s) in the output that you think should not be there, then examine UniqueMFR to see if a copy of it exists.  If there's no copy in UniqueMFR, then the logic of your question say that it should be in the query output.

Comment: @logagi Good to hear!  Don't forget to upvote any answers that were helpful to you and to select the green check if one of the answers solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can always use `Not In`
Usual Syntax:

```
Select * from Table1(164 records) where Id/ItemNum Not In (Query 2)
```

Your Query can be edited as follow to get desired result

```
SELECT NewMNFData.ITEM_NUMBER, NewMNFData.MFR, NewMNFData.MFR_PN
FROM NewMNFData INNER JOIN ([B-K Data] INNER JOIN [BK-Analogic-PN-CDB2006-import] ON [B-K Data].[B-K no] = [BK-Analogic-PN-CDB2006-import].[BK PN]) ON NewMNFData.ITEM_NUMBER = [BK-Analogic-PN-CDB2006-import].[Analogic PN] 
WHERE NewMNFData.ITEM_NUMBER NOT IN (SELECT NewMNFData.ITEM_NUMBER, Min(NewMNFData.MFR) AS MinOfMFR, Min(NewMNFData.MFR_PN) AS MinOfMFR_PN
    FROM NewMNFData INNER JOIN ([B-K Data] INNER JOIN [BK-Analogic-PN-CDB2006-import] ON [B-K Data].[B-K no] = [BK-Analogic-PN-CDB2006-import].[BK PN]) ON NewMNFData.ITEM_NUMBER = [BK-Analogic-PN-CDB2006-import].[Analogic PN]
    GROUP BY NewMNFData.ITEM_NUMBER;)
```

Remember, Apply Where clause condition on attribute on the basis of which your results are different. i.e the unique one

Comment: Unfortuneately I can't search on the ITEM_NUMBER not being in the other query, since the ITEM_NUMBER is in both queries per default.
The item can have 1 to 2 manufacturers, and I try to seperate them in two different batches.